# Why doesn't the descendent's version of an abstract base class's method get called?

Tags: delphi, interface, abstract

I'm trying to create a simple class THistory that has one procedure that takes an abstract base class which implements a simple interface.

The code below compiles, but the THistory class calls the base class HistoryRecords abstract Insert proc instead of the passed in sub classes Insert proc.  What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

```
unit uHistory;

interface

uses Dialogs;

type

IHistoryRecord = interface
  ['{67C90064-1667-4DE0-AF52-11B6E5A00892}']
  procedure Insert();
end;

THistoryRecord = class abstract(TInterfacedObject, IHistoryRecord)
  procedure Insert(); virtual; abstract;
end;

THistory = class(TObject)
  public
  procedure Add(pHistoryRecord : THistoryRecord);
end;

TAlarmHistoryRecord = class(THistoryRecord)
  procedure Insert();
end;

implementation

{ THistory }

procedure THistory.Add(pHistoryRecord: THistoryRecord);
begin
  pHistoryRecord.Insert();
end;

{ TAlarmHistoryRecord }

procedure TAlarmHistoryRecord.Insert;
begin
  MessageDlg('Alarm History Record - Insert Method', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;

end.

Usage
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lHistory : THistory;
  lHistoryRecord : TAlarmHistoryRecord;
begin

  lHistory := THistory.Create();

  lHistoryRecord := TAlarmHistoryRecord.Create();

  // I want this to call the TAlarmsHistoryRecord.Insert proc not the
  // HistoryRecord base class Insert proc.
  lHistory.Add(lHistoryRecord);

end;
```

Comment: Abstract class implementing interface is design nonsense. Use either abstract class or interface, not both.

Comment: In this case, @Serg, you're right: Since THistoryRecord only has one method, and it's not implemented, there's no advantage to descend from that instead of just implementing IHistoryRecord directly. In other cases, though, it can be useful for an abstract class to provide default implementations for *part* of an interface, so descendants can specialize only the parts necessary. TInterfacedObject is a close example; it implements the details of IUnknown so other classes don't have to, but there's never a reason to instantiate TInterfacedObject directly, so it's essentially abstract.

Comment: On the other hand, since the interface type is never referenced in the executable portion of the code — only in the base class declaration — it's not really relevant to this question. Nothing ever accesses a class via the interface, so the interface is a red herring.

Comment: @Rob as you said TInterfacedObject **implements** `IUnknown` methods. Design nonsense is to declare these methods as `virtual; abstract`. I see no reason to do it.

Comment: @Serg, I never said TInterfacedObject was a *perfect* example. A better, but less well known, example might be [my implementation of the ITextHost interface](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/windowless-rtf). My TTextHostImpl class (see *TOM.pas*) implements *most* of ITextHost with sensible defaults, but it has to leave TxGetPropertyBits abstract because I found no appropriate default implementation. Consumers *could* write their own classes from scratch, but descending from TTextHostImpl is convenient since there are lots of methods to implement, and the defaults are fine most of the time.

Comment: @Serg Abstract class or concrete class, it can always make sense to declare that either form of class supports an interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `override` directive in the `TAlarmHistoryRecord` method declaration, ie it should be

```
procedure Insert(); override;
```

Actually the compiler should warn you that the method hides inherited one.

Comment: sorry you are little bit late to answer

Comment: Not only should there have been a warning about hiding the virtual method of the base class, but there should also have been a warning about instantiating a class that still had abstract methods! *Never* ignore a compiler warning, Sean.

Comment: Of course, you have to enable hints and warnings first, in order to see them. :)

Answer (score 8):

You missed the **override**:

```
TAlarmHistoryRecord = class(THistoryRecord)
  procedure Insert(); override;
end;
```